# Cassandra Client Command Line Client Displays Dots

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-cli

I successfully started a Cassandra server instance. When I try to start client instance using the following command

```
bin/cassandra-cli
```

It seems to startup successfully since it displays the following prompt.

```
[default@unknown]
```

However no matter what command I type it always displays three dots:

```
...
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I guess I can answer my own question the ';' at the end was missing. The textbooks did not have it. Looks like that is needed..

Comment: Throw the book away... seriously. If you are using books on cassandra that means the information in it is painfully outdated.

Comment: @Lyuben Todorov +1 Books are woefully outdated. The only catch is that Cassandra along with Hadoop has sparse documentation which forces us to rely on Whitepapers & IEEE Transactions.....